# CFRelease vs CGPathRelease

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, core-foundation

The following is a snippet of code from the [Omni frameworks](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup):

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL/*transform*/, rect);
self->_path = CGPathCreateCopy(path);
CFRelease(path);
```

Why is CFRelease used here instead of CGPathRelease?  Are they the same, and if so, why does the latter exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for CGPathRelease](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathRelease):

> This function is equivalent to
>   CFRelease, except that it does not
>   cause an error if the path parameter
>   is NULL.

In addition to not failing on `NULL` values, you also get a little bit of compile-time type-safety as the parameter is typed as `CGPathRef` rather than `CFTypeRef` (which is equivalent to `void *`).